# How to add classes to dynamically created elements in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

```js
{temp_array_beg.map((el,index) => (
  <div key={index} className="subRenderButton">
      <input type="button" value={el.i} className="paginationBtn" onClick=        {this.handlePaginationClick.bind(this)} />
  </div>
))}
```

Ihave tried Conditional Rendering of class but then all the rendered divs got the active class

Comment: `Ihave tried Conditional Rendering`,  could you show us?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

This library is great for handling conditional classnames.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{temp_array.map((btn,index) => (
     <div key={index} className="subRenderButton">
     <input type="button"value={btn.i} className={["paginationBtn",buttonNumber == btn.i ? "active" :""].join(' ')} onClick={this.handlePaginationClick.bind(this)} />
     </div>
))}
```

I have managed to solve the problem Thanks!